# If I add the "-f" parameter to CURL, how can I display the response body when the status code is not 200?

Tags: http, curl, http-status-codes

I am using curl to make a http request, and I need it to report an error(return not zero) when returning an abnormal status code, so I added the "-f" parameter. But this way, the content of the response body will not be displayed. How to operate curl to report an error when returning an abnormal status code while still displaying the response body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do:

```
curl -sw '%{http_code}\n' https://example.org/xx | tee >(
    hc=$(tail -n1)
    case $hc in
        5*) echo >&2 "5xx range fatal error $hc" ;;
        4*) echo >&2 "4xx range error $hc" ;;
        200) true ;;
        *) echo >&2 "Not 200 HTTP code $hc" ;;
    esac
)
```